# Ansible, hosts management which are behind of a firewall and has dynamic IPs

Tags: ansible, devops

Is it possible use Ansible to hosts managements, if the hosts has dynamic IPs and they could be behind of firewall ?

May be using reverse connection or a reverse proxy ?

Comment: If you have a dynamic dns you can address the machines using their fqdn. For the firewall, you need port 22 opened to your machine, or access to a rebound host, or a vpn connection.... This is a rather broad question, please read [what topic can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help section.

Comment: The topic of my question refers to Ansible as i mention in the subject. The machine hasn't domain name, they are desktops, so use  dynamic DNS isn't an option. Regarding firewalls, they aren't mine, so i can't manage them.